# How to go down in an arry and get specific object

Tags: php

Ok so i have this array

```
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 20,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": "techcrunch",
        "name": "TechCrunch"
      },
      "author": "Emma Lee",
      "title": "The incredible rise of Pinduoduo, China's newest force in e-commerce",
      "description": "Editor’s note: This post originally appeared on TechNode, an editorial partner of TechCrunch based in China. From Alibaba to JD, China is not short of e-commerce powerhouses. Although the country’s e-commerce market is highly consolidated, it’s not impossible…",
      "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/07/26/the-incredible-rise-of-pinduoduo/",
      "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Pinduoduo.jpeg?w=750",
      "publishedAt": "2018-07-27T03:39:00Z"
    },
```

This works so far for me, since i don't have to go lower in the array.

```
echo $queries['status'];
echo '<br />';
echo "Total Results: ". $queries['totalResults'];
```

But if i Try to do

```
echo $queries['author'];
```

It will not work.

Comment: Loop over `$queries['articles']`

Comment: echo $queries['articles'][0]['author'];

Comment: The zero in @Lixas comment designates the first returning value only, so if this was a loop somewhere, you would need to factor accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`articles` contains an array of object and author is inside an `array of object` of articles. If you want to get the author then you should apply loop on $queries.

```
foreach ($queries as $query ) {
    echo $query['articles']->author;
}
```

or you can get it direct as:

```
$queries['articles'][0]->author
```

Answer (score 1):

you're working with `JSON` object, this first needs converting into a `PHP` object. Cannot access `JSON` object directly so convert your object into string.

```
$queries = '{
     "status": "ok",
       ..........
    }';

$queries = json_decode($queries);

$articles = $queries->articles;

    foreach ($articles as $articleKey => $articleVal) {
        echo articleVal->author;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original query appeared that there was only one article being returned. The code you originally posted is try to access the author key within the top of the array, but the author key is actually nested under the articles array. Here is what I would try, for only retrieving the active author:

```
echo $queries["articles"][0]["author"];
```

Comment: And if i would like to access the id ?. This is what i tried. echo "ID: " . $queries['articles'][0]['source'][0]['id'];

Comment: Try `echo "ID: " . $queries['articles'][0]['source'][0]->id; `

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($queries['articles'] as $article) {
    echo $article->author;
}
```

Try this

Comment: 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: However, this will get ALL author names, OP wants just the author from the query.